# Timed transition between image swaps with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have this code:

```
$('.pic_windows img').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).effect('shake', {
        times : 4,
        distance : 5
    }, 15).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/.jpg/, '-1.jpg'))
});

$('.pic_windows img').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/-1.jpg/, '.jpg'))
});
```

where I'm using JQuery's .attr to swap the images, but I'd like the swapping to occur over the course of around 1 second.  I've googled this and get all these complicated "CSS3 transitions with JQuery fallback" tutorials.  Is there a way to 'animate' an .attr change?

I think I should do a fadeOut while the other fadeIn but I don't know how to write it, as I'm almost a complete JQuery newbie.  I have a number of these transitions to do over the course of several pages.  It'd be a cinch if I needed to write this for just one instance.

**UPDATE**  On mouseenter, the image shakes and then should during this shake, fade from one picture to its swapped picture.  On mouseleave, the image should just fade back to the original picture.  Unfortunately I have also found that the shake effect is breaking on IE, all versions, as well as the image swap (it doesn't see image 2 at all)

Comment: Can you describe the complete effect you would like to see, on mouseenter and on mouseleave?

Comment: revised answer for updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot animate an attribute change. What you can do is clone an element, change an attribute and transition between them.

```
var target = $(this).fadeOut();
var src = target.attr('src').replace(/-1.jpg/, '.jpg');
var copy = target.clone()
    .attr('src', src)
    .hide()
    .insertAfter(target)
    .fadeIn();
```

**EDIT:** Thank you for clarifying your intentions, I would advise not playing with the 'src', which will essentially require building a small stateful plugin. Instead, stick with the desired effect here, reveal an image on hover. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eHQ3t/13/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="shaker">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-360-240-3.jpg" />
    <img class="hover" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-360-240-9.jpg" />
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.shaker {
    position: relative;
}
.shaker img {
    position: absolute;
}
.hover {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.shaker').hover(function () {
    $(this).effect('shake', {
        times: 4,
        distance: 5
    }, 15);
    $(this).find('.hover').fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.hover').stop().fadeOut();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHQ3t/13/

Comment: It works up until the clone part.  Then I get a FOUC that is outside the container it should be in, and mouseenter functionality breaks.  If I put this part into both mouseenter and mouseleave events (swapping from .jpg to -1.jpg) it REALLY breaks (images disappear altogether and don't come back).

Comment: for sure it breaks your other binds, you will need to either add your binds to new content or delegate the event handlers to something higher up the chain using `.on()`. to remove FOUC you'll need to position them absolutely.

Comment: That worked!  (Although now my CSS is a little wonky between browsers, but I'll figure that one out)  Thanks a lot!